# Pcapture Arrival time latency on long capture

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I am using dumpcap to capture over a period of 30 mins or so.

Initially the Arrival time is very close to the Send time in the messages I receive (FIX).

But there is then a progressive loss of time as the pcap runs, which adds up to 50ms+ after 20 mins.

I noticed this in WireShark, and thought it was because of the GUI overhead but it is in dumpcap too.

Is there a way around this?

This is my command line:

```
dumpcap.exe -i 5 -a filesize:20000000 -w output0405v1.pcapng
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `.exe`, I'm going to assume you're on the Windows platform.  Further, I'll assume that you're using WinPcap as the actual capture driver.

Probably the best way to understand the timestamping done by WinPcap is to follow an old thread on the Wireshark-users mailing list, with the subject, ["Wireshark time behind the actual time"](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201008/msg00164.html).

Within the thread, Gianluca Varenni, one of the creators, if not ***THE*** creator of WinPcap, mentions a Windows Registry Setting that can be tweaked, namely `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NPF\TimestampMode`, and which might possibly improve your timestamps.  To quote Gianluca:

---

Possible values are

- 0 (default) -> Timestamps generated through KeQueryPerformanceCounter, less reliable on SMP/HyperThreading machines, precision = some microseconds
- 2 -> Timestamps generated through KeQuerySystemTime, more reliable on SMP/HyperThreading machines, precision = scheduling quantum (10/15 ms)
- 3 -> Timestamps generated through the i386 instruction RDTSC, less reliable on SMP/HyperThreading/SpeedStep machines, precision = some microseconds

After you change the setting (you want use 2), you need to restart the NPF driver by opening an elevated command prompt and running "net stop npf" followed by "net start npf".

---

Alternatively, you could try replacing [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/) with the much more modern [npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) and see if that driver performs better.